# Как получить доступ к порту контейнера/сервиса в swarm не публикуя порт во внешний мир

Tags: postgresql, сеть, iptables, docker-swarm

Можно в docker-compose сделать проброс порта в контейнер только с `localhost`, прописав в `docker-compose.yml` нужную кофигурацию `ports`, например `127.0.0.1:8080:80`.

В docker swarm такое не работает, и опубликованный порт виден из интернета.

Как тогда получить доступ к порту контейнера только с localhost, не открывая доступ к порту в интернет?

Пробовал настроить iptables на запрет подключения к порту `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DROP`, но из-за настроек от docker для iptables, такое не сработало.

Контекст задачи такой, у меня есть контейнер с postgres, и я бы хотел подключась через ssh тунель к удаленному серверу подключиться к БД с моего компа. Знаю что можно установить что-то вроде adminer рядом с самой БД, и его уже выводить через reverse-proxy в веб. Но есть более удобное для меня приложение ValentinaStudio, через которое хотелось бы подключаться к БД

Comment: Попробуйте ничего не пробрасывая обратится с локалхоста к пору контейнера (указывая ip контейнера), по идее он должен быть доступен и так

Answer (score 0):

К контейнеру можно обратиться через ip, который принадлежит интерфейсу `docker_gwbridge`.

Узнать ip адрес контейнера в интерфейсе `docker_gwbridge` мне удалось запуском команды `ifconfig` в самом контейнере:

```bsh
$ docker exec <container-id> ifconfig
```

Таким образом доступ к контейнеру можно получить с `localhost`, например, по `172.18.0.2:5432`, без необходимости опубликовывать порт `5432`.

---

Попытка узнать ip адрес через `docker inspect <container-id> (or <service-name> or <network-id>)` в swarm сервисах не привели к желаемому результату, т.к. там не отображался ip из интерфейса `docker_gwbridge`. А "внутренние" ip (что-то вроде 10.0.4.6) были не доступны с `localhost`.